# Advanced Custom Fields repeater delete_post_meta hooks passing the wrong meta

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to run some additional functions when updating and deleting ACF custom post meta, ACF version 4.3.8. The ACF field type is a repeater with several rows. When I delete one of these rows, I'm getting the wrong $meta_key passed to my hook:

```
<?php

class My_Consultant_Save_Post {

    function __construct() {

        add_action( 'delete_post_meta', array ( $this, 'delete_consultant_meta_connections'), 10, 4 );

    }

    public function delete_consultant_meta_connections( $meta_id, $post_id, $meta_key, $_meta_value ) {

        echo 'post_id';
        var_dump($post_id);

        echo 'meta_key';
        var_dump($meta_key);

        echo 'current value of meta, before deleting';
        $current = get_post_meta($post_id, $meta_key);
        var_dump($current); 

        die;

    }
}

$my_consultant_update = new My_Consultant_Save_Post();
```

see [delete_postmeta](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.0/src/wp-includes/meta.php#L293) function, and the action [delete_post_meta](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.0/src/wp-includes/meta.php#L368)

actually it appears to be passing the $meta_key of the last row entry I have in the field group's repeater field, and definitely not one that I deleted from the front-end post editor's acf remove row button.

Any ideas why the hook is not returning the meta_key of the actual meta I tried to delete?

Comment: Can you supply some more code? Also what version of ACF are you using? 5.0 was a pretty big upgrade

Comment: Thanks, updated question with more code. ACF version 4.3.8.

Comment: Well, according to this post, http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/26438 , by sebastien.b, my hook may not have time to get the post meta that is queued to be deleted before it is actually deleted. I'm saving posts after deleting the meta manually from the ui so i suppose my hook is too late.

Comment: why do you want it to die/exit? You are actually answering the question yourself with your previous comment: remove the `die;` and it should work as expected.